# Calling method from subclass results in "no superclass method `sign_up_params' for ...". Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

**Background**

I have subclassed `Devise::RegistrationsController` to handle User registrations myself with a class named `DeviseUsersController`.

I need to override the `create` action - I had previously used `super` then performed the additional things that needed to be done, however, this no longer will satisfy my requirements.

So I checked out the [devise code on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) and tried to recreate it with a few adjustments. However, I have had problems starting with the first line...

**The Code**

```
class DeviseUsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...

  def build_resource
    super
  end

  def sign_up_params
    super
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    ...
  end

end
```

**The Error**

```
super: no superclass method `sign_up_params' for #<DeviseUsersController:0x007f8f2d09a538>
```

**The Question**

Why is this error occurring? Based on the [Devise::RegistrationsController code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) it is evident that the method, which is not private, exists.

*Versions:*

- Rails 3.2.13
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Devise 2.2.3

**EDIT**
Changing the code to:

```
class DeviseUsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    ...
  end

  protected

  def build_resource
    super
  end

  def sign_up_params
    super
  end

end
```

still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that, based on the Devise::RegistrationsController code, the method exists in **Gem  v3.0.0**, I happen to have Gem v2.2.3 installed.

I decided to use `gem unpack devise` to look at the source code for the version I had installed. The implementation of the controller is different than v3.0.0 and this version does not have a `sign_up_params` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch it carefully, you'll see `protected` before a bunch of methods including `sign_up_params`.

Well, I have to say it's really not significant, I use my local repo so I can find it :)

In your sub class, your method `sign_up_params` is a public method. In fact there is really no such public method in parent class. The error is correct.

To solve, I think you can set the method `sign_in_params` in subclass as protected, though I have not verified that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. See edited post.

Comment: @user2460234, when you say "did not solve the problem", would you give  the specific error, I have no way to know by a general "didn't work"

Comment: I apologize, since I edited only the code portion of my question I assumed it was clear the error was the exact same.

Comment: @user2460234, that's fine. I met the same problem before and I ended up using Rails traditional param methods like `resource = params[:user]` because I didn't have time, and it works. I have not seen any problem. This is one solution. The other is to copy `sign_up_param` method into your controller with same code which is one line only, instead of calling `super`, but I'm not sure if the code inside will work.